# How to fetch all the Todo lists and its corresponding Todos for a project from New Basecamp (bcx) API

Tags: ios, uitableview, basecamp

**REFERRED** https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todos.md and https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todolists.md

**TRIED** hitting the /todolists.json Basecamp bcx API (since I needed to show the todo lists as header/sections of the tableview displaying Project Todos).

**GOT** *Names* of the todo lists, their *Descriptions* (if any), and their respective *URLs* (amidst other not-so-useful-to-me info.)

Now, I have already used this URL (above) and hit it to fetch the list of todos (both completed and remaining) for that particular todo-list and got what I intended to; storing and displaying them, dynamically.

*However, to me, this approach seems a bit amateurish as I am,
a) storing the todo list in a mutable-array..
b) hitting the API for each object of this mutable-array (above) and fetching an array of todos for a particular todo-list..
c) storing this list (of todos) in a mutable-dictionary - key for which is the name of the todo-list..
and finally,
d) using this mutable-dictionary in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods for dynamically setting the tableView height and objects, respectively..*

**INTEND TO** Get all the todo lists for a project WITH its corresponding todos as a response of a single Basecamp bcx API, for:

a) Improving the code quality,
b) Decreasing the iteration time,
c) Preventing headache of a person, if any, who is going to parse my code later in future

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't possible with the BCX API. If you want to see all of the todos on an individual project's todolists, you'll need to [get each todolist](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todolists.md#get-todolist) separately.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is probably available in the new API update. Kindly check.

Comment: No @BhawaniSingh.
I checked the [#get-to-do-list](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todolists.md#get-to-do-list) anchor under the `get-to-do-lists` API and particularly, its `exclude_todos` parameter. Thought it might be the solution, but it ain't, because in any case one has to specify the todo-list for which the to-dos are to be fetched. :(